# finding a close enough point with implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, implicit-function-theorem

Let $a_1, ...,a_n ,B\in \mathbb{R}^n$ , not all on the same plane.

Prove that for a small enough neighborhood of zero $U$ and $\forall u_1,...,u_n \in U $ there is a point $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that

$\forall k : 1\leq k\leq n :|C-a_k|= |B-a_k|+u_k $

moreover, is this point unique?

I tried to use the implicit function theorem for the function $f(X,y)=|X-a_k|-|B-a_k|+y$ for the point $(B,0)$ somehow. How should i continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $F:\mathbb R^{2n}\to\mathbb R^n$ as
$$
F(u_1,\cdots,u_n,C)=\begin{bmatrix}
u_1+|B-a_1|-|C-a_1|\\
\vdots\\
u_k+|B-a_k|-|C-a_k|
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
F_1(u_1,\cdots,u_n,C)\\
\vdots\\
F_n(u_1,\cdots,u_n,C)
\end{bmatrix}\\\\
F(0,\cdots,0,B)=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$
Use $${\partial |C-a_i|\over\partial C_j}={\partial \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n(C_k-a_{ik})^2}\over\partial C_j}={(C_j-a_{ij})\over|C-a_i|}$$
to see that
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
{\partial F_1\over\partial C_1}\;\cdots\;{\partial F_1\over\partial C_n}\\
\vdots\\
{\partial F_n\over\partial C_1}\;\cdots\;{\partial F_n\over\partial C_n}
\end{bmatrix}\Big{|}_{(0,\cdots,0,B)}\\$$
has 
$$
{B-a_i\over|B-a_i|}
$$
as its $i$-th row. If these vectors are linearly independent $\det J\neq0$. Then according to implicit function theorem $\exists$ open sets  $U,V\subset\mathbb R^n$ containing $(0,\cdots,0),B$ respectively and a unique $\mathcal C^1$ function $g:U\to V:$ 
$$
x\in U\implies F(x,g(x))=[0,\cdots,0]^\top
$$
So $g(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ is the required $C$. Uniqueness of $g$ implies uniqueness of $C$. I think it might be helpful if you take a look at my answer to [another implicit function theorem question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830853/for-f-a-bx-2xa-b-abx4-show-that-for-x-1-x-2-close-enough-to-2-3/1832121#1832121).

Comment: I was almost there, thank's :)